# Jquery scroll to top offset is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.slider-down").click(function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about-full").offset(70).top
    }, 1500);
});
});
```

How to set offset value to this script? This code is wrote for scroll to top when click link. `offset(70)` not working

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass any value in [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2) function it take object having `top` and `left` keys, change the below code

```
scrollTop: $("#about-full").offset(70).top
```

to

```
scrollTop: $("#about-full").offset().top
```

And if you want to set top only for `70` then use,

```
scrollTop: 70
```

Comment: scrollTop: $("#about-full").offset().top - 70 is working

Comment: hmm I missed this option

Answer (score 0):

Change the line where you assign to **scrollTop** as follows:

```
scrollTop: $("#about-full").offset().top - 70
```

This is working.